# datatables js grid: handle dbl click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, datatables

I try to handle double click event on row for a table with jquery datatables
As you can see I try few things, inside fnDrawCallback, inside document ready with on() or directly dblckick() but it never work;-(
It only work when I set it up on table element but with that, I do not get the row element ;-(

here is the code:

```
$(document).ready (function() {
$("#wfTable").dataTable( {
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "server/workflows",
    "bScrollInfinite": true,
   "bScrollCollapse": true,
   "sScrollY": "200px",
   "iScrollLoadGap": 50,
   "aoColumns": [
    { "sTitle": "Id",   "mData": "id" },
    { "sTitle": "Label", "mData": "label" },
    { "sTitle": "Name" ,"mData": "name" }],
    "fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {
        var oTable = $('#wfTable TR');
        var theData = oTable.find('TR');
        theData.unbind();
        //  On row click, go to single-view page
        theData.dblclick( function (e) {
            var iPos = oTable.fnGetPosition( this );
            var aData = oTable.fnGetData( iPos );
            var iId = aData[0];
        });
    }
});/*fnServerData  bJQueryUI true*/

//$('#wfTable').dblclick( function (e) {
/*$('#wfTable td').on("dblclick", function() {
    //target = $(e.target);

    //while(target.get(0).tagName != "TR"){
    //  target = target.parent();
    //}
    var iPos = oTable.fnGetPosition( this );
    var aData = oTable.fnGetData( iPos );
    var iId = aData[0];

    window.location.href = 'workflow/' + iId;
});*/
```

});

Comment: I have near succeed with : `$('#wfTable').dblclick( function (e) {
 //$('#wfTable td').on("dblclick", function() {
  target = $(e.target);

  while(target.get(0).tagName != "TR"){
   target = target.parent();
  }

  var iPos = oTable.fnGetPosition( target.get() );
  var aData = oTable.fnGetData( iPos );
  var iId = aData[0];

  window.location.href = 'workflow/' + iId;
 });` but I get a error because can not get nodeName wereas chrome show this attribut in debug mode ;-(

Answer (score 0):

I found this:

```
    $('#wfTable').dblclick( function (e) {
    target = $(e.target);

    while(target.get(0).tagName != "TR"){
        target = target.parent();
    }

    var iPos = oTable.fnGetPosition( target.get(0) );
    var aData = oTable.fnGetData( iPos );
    var iId = aData.id;

    window.location.href = 'workflow/' + iId;
});
```

anyway your code must work too

Comment: This will target a dblclick on your table not on your tablerows.
Try to reference a row and therefore reference to a column to get any Id.

Comment: e.g. 
`$(document).on("dblclick", "#wfTable tr", function(event) {
    var id = $("anyColumn", this);
});`

Answer (score 0):

One working answer from 2023

This code came from the DataTable Forum:

```
  $(document).ready( function () { 
       var table = $('#example').DataTable(); 
       $('#example tbody').on( 
      'dblclick', 
      'tr', 
      function () { 
        var data = table.row( this ).data(); 
        alert("id is " +  data["0"]); 
      } 
    ); 
   });
```

We have a datatable, where the id is in the first row (data[0]).